# Google Chrome starting up slow

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

Whenever I try to open Chrome for the first time after booting, it takes about 8-10 seconds longer than it does for Windows. Is this the case for everyone? Is there a way to fix it?
I know it is not that much of an important problem but it bothers to wait that long while the process is instant on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This sound like an issue with `Chrome`. However, you can install this daemon which will significantly improve launching apps on start-up. It is called `Preload`. Here is the summary of what `Preload`, taken from the `Ubuntu Software Center`:

> preload monitors applications that users run, and by analyzing this data, predicts what applications users might run, and fetches those binaries and their dependencies into memory for faster startup times.
>
> Note that installing preload will not make your system boot faster and that preload is a daemon that runs with root priviledges.

I have used it, and found that when I get to my desktop, from boot, programs like Firefox, launch significantly faster.

To install it, either open the `Ubuntu Software Center`, and search for `preload`, or for `Terminal` users, open the `terminal` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

Simple as that. Please report if it make Chrome open quicker. I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard some people talking about the same issue, so I assume it's normal.

Is it a desktop PC or a laptop? Laptops have 5400 rpm hard disks installed and those are really a performance bottlenecks. I've recently upgraded to a 7200 rpm HDD and the performance is significantly better.

Comment: Let's **assume**, even though OP hasn't explicitly said so, that the **only variable** is the OS. All other things, including browser settings, are unchanged. Otherwise, possibilities are too numerous.

Comment: This is on exactly the same laptop. Interesting thing is, first launch of Chrome is slow, if I close and open it again after launching for the first time, it is not distinguishably slow if not faster. So I think it is an OS issue, but I have limited knowledge about such things and I can only guess that it has something to do with the services running (in Ubuntu's case, not running) on startup on both OS's.

Comment: Actually it's not an issue, but a side effect of computer's and OS'es mechanics. On Windows the Chrome's first start is also slower, but you haven't noticed it as it's almost instant. On slower PCs it's clearly noticeable. And it affects not only Chrome, but all other apps too.